# I am trying to do a find for folders begining with "of" and get their folder sizes

Tags: find, size, du

Strangely this command works perfectly on 2 SLES11 servers, but not another. Here is my command ...

```
du `find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\*` -hs
```

and I get a result like ...

```
du: invalid option -- 'I'
du: invalid option -- 'n'
du: invalid option -- 't'
du: invalid option -- 'e'
du: invalid option -- 'r'
du: invalid option -- 'v'
du: invalid option -- 'i'
du: invalid option -- 'e'
du: invalid option -- 'w'
du: invalid option -- '/'
du: invalid option -- 'o'
du: invalid option -- 'f'
du: invalid option -- 'd'
du: invalid option -- 'j'
du: invalid option -- 'r'
du: invalid option -- 'I'
du: invalid option -- 'n'
```

And this is the result from an identically built server ...

```
du `find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\*` -hs
200K    ./xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/of19darc
6.4G    ./xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ofkuoarc
188K    ./xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ofkuoarc/ofkuoarc
180K    ./xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx//data/Archive/ofw68arc
du: cannot access `yyy/Cyyyyy/GW': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `Archive/of19darc': No such file or directory

etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
du `find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\*` -hs
```

Will fail on any files that contain whitespace and will attempt to treat files starting with `-` (or having `-` after whitespace) as options to `du`.

Try something like

```
find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\* -exec du -hs -- {} \;
```

or if your `find` supports it (the faster)

```
find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\* -exec du -hs -- {} +
```

Comment: find -maxdepth 7 -type d -name of\* -exec du -hs -- {} \; works without the '' around the of - really appreciate your prompt answers and enlightment

Comment: @tomc You're right. For some reason I swapped the escape with something else in my hand, the escape and quotes should work equally well. Glad the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
du -h $(find . -type d -name 'of*')
```